# Installing Perl/Tk on fedora

Tags: perl, fedora, perltk

I am having trouble trying to install perl Tk on my system(fedora,perl v5.8.8).I downloaded the tarred module from http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Tk-804.029/pod/gencmd, untarred it.In the terminal,I gave "perl Makefile.PL" which worked fine and then "make" which could not complete.Here is what it gave:

```
"make[1]: Entering directory `/work/harikal/Tk-804.029/pTk'
gcc -c  -I..  -I. -Ibitmaps  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/gdbm -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables   -DVERSION=\"804.029\" -DXS_VERSION=\"804.029\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   -Wall -Wno-implicit-int -Wno-comment -Wno-unused -D__USE_FIXED_PROTOTYPES__ tkImgPhoto.c
tkImgPhoto.c: In function ‘AllocateColors’:
tkImgPhoto.c:3584: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sazeof’
tkImgPhoto.c:3584: error: expected expression before ‘XColor’
make[1]: *** [tkImgPhoto.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/work/harikal/Tk-804.029/pTk'
make: *** [pTk/libpTk.a] Error 2"
```

and then it exits. What am I supposed to do??
Please Help

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the system-installed Perl, then why not use the Fedora project's pre-built package for the module.

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Tk
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/SREZIC/Tk-804.029/pTk/mTk/generic/tkImgPhoto.c - line 3584 and here says "sizeof" not "sazeof".  Doublecheck your source/download.